# Test fails when @AfterTest annotation is changed to @Test

Tags: selenium

I have following class file

```
public class AuthenticationTest extends Base {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AuthenticationTest.class.getName());
    private static WebDriver driver;
    LoginPageFactory lp;

    @BeforeTest
    public void initialize() {
        //ExtentReport.config(LoginTest.class.getName());
        log.debug("Initializing WebDriver");
        driver = getDriver();   
        log.debug("Driver is Initialized");
        driver.get(p.getProperty("url"));
        log.debug("Navigated to Login page");

    }


    @Test
    public void login() {               

                try {       

                Map<String,String> data = ExcelUtil.getData("R1SanityTestData.xlsx", "LoginTest", "ValidLoginTest");

                lp = new LoginPageFactory(driver);
                log.debug("LoginPageFactory class initialized");

                lp.txtUsername().click();
                lp.txtUsername().clear();
                lp.txtUsername().sendKeys(data.get("UserName"));
                log.debug("Username entered");
                lp.txtPassword().clear();
                lp.txtPassword().sendKeys(data.get("Password"));
                log.debug("Password entered");
                lp.btnLogin().click();
                log.debug("Login button clicked");  

                LandingPageFactory lpf = new LandingPageFactory(driver);    

                Assert.assertEquals(lpf.lblAppName().getText(), "OD App");
                Assert.assertTrue(lpf.iconProfile().isDisplayed());
                log.info("Login Success");
                String path = Screenshot.takeScreenshot(driver, "LoginTest/LoginStatus");
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    log.fatal("IOException in LoginTest");
                    log.fatal(e.getMessage() +" : " + e.getStackTrace());
                    driver.quit();
                }
                catch(NoSuchElementException e){
                    log.fatal("NosuchElementException in LoginTest");
                    log.fatal(e.getMessage() +" : " + e.getStackTrace());
                    driver.quit();
                }

                catch(Exception e) {
                    log.fatal("Exception in LoginTest");
                    log.fatal(e.getMessage() +" : " + e.getStackTrace());
                    driver.quit();
                }

    }               

    @AfterTest
    public void logOut() {
        CommonPageFactory cpf = new CommonPageFactory(driver);
        cpf.linkViewProfile().click();      
        log.debug("View Profile Clicked");  
        cpf.linkLogOut().click();       
        log.debug("Log Out Clicked");
        driver.quit();
    }   
}
```

When I run this class individually (Run AS --> TestNG Test), then above test works fine. But when I change the annotation of the logOut() method to @Test then login method passes but takes quite a lot of time to execute and logOut test fails with org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException for first element.

**Console output**:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.1
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d833300373761342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 42250
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 31, 2020 8:14:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
PASSED: login
FAILED: logOut
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[data-aura-class='uiImage']"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)

My WebDriver is static and is derived from the Base class. I am using test 7.1.0. What could be the issue?

I searched on the forum but could not find the answer.

Comment: does your testng config have setup for parallel execution?

Comment: No. This is my testng file:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="R1 Sanity">
<listeners>
 <listener class-name="utils.Listeners" />
</listeners>

 
    
    <test name="Consumer Bureau Test">
    <classes>
     <class name="com.xxx.xxxxx.R1.sanity.CheckConsumerBureauTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  
   <test name="Upload Bank statement and Check data">
  <classes>
   <class name="com.xxx.xxxxxxx.R1.sanity.BSATest"/>
  </classes>
  </test>
  
</suite>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dependsOn or use a priority in your test annotations. @Test methods are not always executed in the same order as they are written. Also if the Tests are run in parallel this would be an issue as well. **Since logOut is completely dependent on the login method, try using**

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods ="login")
public void logOut() {
....}
```

dependsOn will make sure to run the logOut method only after the login method has completed successfully or passed.

Comment: Correct annotation is @Test(dependsOnMethods = "login") which gives the expected result.